# Live form validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to do live form validation using javascript like if I type number in text field it should give error message instantly or vice versa.How can I achieve this.

Comment: Please show some attempts/code so that we may be able to help better

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by detecting changes in the input entries. You can do that easily by using the `oninput` event (read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)).

Looking at that example:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
   console.log("input event detected! coming from this element:", e.target);
  }, false);
</script>

<input placeholder="type here and see console.">
```

Each time your input value changes, an event will be fired an received in that listener.

In your case, you need to add an event listener for each of the inputs and, instead of doing a `console.log` in the handler function, just call a generic function that will validate all the values for all the inputs in the form.

For the validations, you can look at multiple libraries, like [validate.js](https://github.com/ansman/validate.js) or [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org). Also, take a look at [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js).